# ¿Como guardar datos desde un formulario a una tabla momentáneamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Se que este tipo de preguntas no son válidas en la comunidad pero estuve buscando información toda la tarde.
Pues quiero implementar este tipo de formularios antes de que se envíen al controlador.
¿Alguien sabe como lo puedo realizar? 
O tienen algún ejemplo que hayan visto, me ayudarían de mucho.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes guardar los datos que quieras en localstorage.

*nota: antes de guardar convertirlo a string, con JSON.stringify()*

```
localStorage.setItem("nombreVariable",datoAGuardar);
```

y lo recuperas de la siguiente manera:

```
var datoRecuperado=localStorage.getItem("nombreVariable");
```

mas informacion: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

> como mandaríamos después de registrar en el localstore a nuestra base
>   de datos?

debes usar ajax para el envio de datos de javascript hacia un lenguaje de servidor.

**ejemplo de envio de variables de js a php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>login</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).on('load', function() {           

            var datoAenviar = 'idUsuario';

            $('#botonEnviar').click(function(event) {               

                event.preventDefault();

                var request = $.ajax({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url    : 'login.php',//el archivo server .php al que quieres enviar                    
                    data   : {
                        dato : datoAenviar//dato que quieres enviar
                    },
                    dataType    : 'json' //el tipo de dato tambien puede ser text
                });

                request.done(function(response) { 
                    if(response.status) {
                        alert('Success: ' + response.result + "\n Message: " + response.message);
                        window.location.href = 'login.php';
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error: ' + response.message);
                        window.location.href = window.location.href;
                    }
                });

                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert("Server request failed: " + textStatus);
                    window.location.href = '';
                });
            });

        });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formulario">
            <p><input type="text "id="clickme"  placeholder="n o m b r e"></p>
            <p><input type="text "id="pass"  placeholder=" c o n t r a s e n a"></p>
            <input type="button" id="botonEnviar" value="enviar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

y el server login.php: tiene que recibir la variable dato

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['dato'])){//recuperas el dato
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $resultado = $_POST['dato'];

    echo json_encode(array(//pruebas si funciona imprimiendolo
        'status' => 1,
        'result' => $resultado,
        'message' => "Todo bien"
    ), true);
}
```

con los datos recuperados debes hacer las debidas consultas para insertar en la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, donde podría encontrar mas información del tema?

Comment: @AnthonySanchez edite mi respuesta, dejando un link

Comment: Gracias........

Comment: Y como mandaríamos después de registrar en el localstore a nuestra base de datos?

Comment: @AnthonySanchez modifique mi respuesta, respondiendo a tu ultima pregunta

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres hacer una especie de sesión offline, puedes guardar los nuevos registros de manera local. Hay distintas maneras, una es usando una base de datos embebida como [LokiJS](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS) o [alaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). Si la aplicación es pequeña puedes usar `local/session storage`.

Por ejemplo, usando [alaSQL](https://github.com/agershun/alasql):

```
window.db = alasql;

db('CREATE TABLE clientes ...');

$('#form-new-customer').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let customer = $(this).serializeArray();
  db.tables.clientes.data.push(customer);
});

// obtener los registros (array de objetos)
let records = db('SELECT * FROM clientes');
```

Si quieres una base de datos cliente al estilo MongoDB, entonces te gustará LokiJS.

Si los registros son pocos, entonces te basta con usar [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

```
$('#form-new-customer').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let customer = $(this).serializeArray();
  let customers = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItems('clientes'));
  customers.push(customer);

  sessionStorage.setItem('clientes', JSON.stringify(customers));
});
```

> ¿Y cómo mandaríamos después de registrar en el localstore a nuestra base de datos?

Mediante una petición AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/clientes',
  type: 'POST',
  data: customers
})
.done(function (resp) {
  // registro correcot
});
```

Comment: Muy bueno, justo estaba buscando una información así. Será que puedas ayudarme con tu ejemplo?

Comment: Publica una nueva pregunta con tu duda.