# ¿Como guardar datos del localstorage a mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, local-storage

Existe alguna manera de poder enviar los datos almacenados en localstorage a a una base de datos? (mysql)

Ejemplo:

Como podemos ver en la imagen podemos tener muchos registros en la lista, y al momento de darle en guardar quiero que se almacene en mi base de datos recién.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo el porque de agregar primero a la tabla y después a la bd?
Con ajax podrías hacer las 2 al mismo tiempo, esto si el problema es recargar la página.

Comment: Respondí a esta pregunta (de paso) en tu pregunta anterior. Revísala.

Comment: @AnthonySanchez esta pregunta es la misma que hiciste anteriormente

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como guardar datos desde un formulario a una tabla momentáneamente?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52100/como-guardar-datos-desde-un-formulario-a-una-tabla-moment%c3%a1neamente)